# How to get the count to binding expression

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a mat-badge which displays the number from

> studentDetails.length

Instead I want to use the number only when

> (studentDetails.length > 0)

HTML:

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{studentDetails.length}}" matBadgeColor="primary">home</mat-icon>
```

Here is an example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-badge-counter-auggsy) to what I am referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mat-badge` can be hidden when no item is present with either of these two syntaxes:

```
[matBadge]="studentDetails?.length || null"

[matBadge]="studentDetails?.length" [matBadgeHidden]="studentDetails?.length < 1"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-badge-counter-e1tq2h?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo. I added the safe navigation operator `?.` for extra protection.

Answer (score 1):

below code works. Just check if the matBadge input is 0, then put null as matBadge input. like this:

```
<mat-icon [matBadge]="studentDetails.length == 0 : null ? studentDetails.length" matBadgeColor="primary">home</mat-icon>
```

I just changed your stackblitz's code a little bit. See here
 [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-badge-counter-e4jgfc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional binding for the attribute:

```
[matBadge]="studentDetails ? studentDetails.length : ''"
```

This should show this if the array is empty or undefined:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to check for

```
studentDetails.length > 0
```

by a ternary operator. If the condition is true use the length, instead use null.

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{ studentDetails.length > 0 ? studentDetails.length : null }}" matBadgeColor="primary">home</mat-icon>
```

This would be the solution which will not modify your implementation very much.

To prevent performance issues use an extra var for the attribute matBadge, which will be modified if the length of studentDetails is changed, because the statement with the ternary operator will be executed by angular every time the change detection triggers.

I also modified your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-badge-counter-qyy8sj) with a more performant version.